# VRaptor - Upload de arquivos no IE 8/9 não funciona

Tags: java, internet-explorer, vraptor, cross-browser

Estou tentando fazer um upload de arquivos e não está funcionando no IE 8.

*OBS.: Funciona no Chrome e no Firefox perfeitamente.*

Andei pesquisando e vi que o IE 8/9 não suportam `FormData` como `enctype`. Ex:

```
<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/xpto/upload">
```

Contudo, segundo a [documentação do vRaptor](http://www.vraptor.org/pt/docs/download-e-upload/) esse enctype é necessário para eu receber o meu `UploadFile` instanciado no Controller. Ex.:

```
@Post("/xpto/upload") 
public void upload(UploadedFile arquivos[])
```

E, de fato, eu testei no Chrome e quando eu não coloco o `enctype="multipart/form-data"` os meus arquivos (`UploadFile arquivos[]`) vem com `null`, quando eu coloco funciona corretamente.

Diante dessa situação gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de eu conseguir fazer com que o meu upload funcione no vRaptor no IE 8 sem eu precisar utilizar o `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser que não esteja funcionando no IE 8/9 pela página estar sendo carregada em modo de compatibilidade.

De qualquer forma, tente colocar também o atributo *encoding*, com o mesmo valor do *enctype*:

```
<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data" action="/xpto/upload">
```

Não tem problema ter os dois, funciona bem em todos os navegadores.